# Двоеточие после "а именно"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли в этих случаях двоеточие после "а именно"? Перечисления здесь нет, но при желании можно разделить эти действия на несколько. Может, просто убрать этот союз? Смысл от этого не потеряется.

Одновременно с принятием решения о предстоящем увольнении работников должно быть изменено штатное расписание организации, а именно (:) соответствующие должности должны быть ликвидированы или должно быть сокращено их количество.

В соответствии со ст. 269 ТК РФ, установлены особенности увольнения несовершеннолетних работников, а именно (:) такое увольнение возможно только с согласия государственной инспекции труда и комиссии по делам несовершеннолетних и защите их прав.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем предложении после "а именно" нужно поставить двоеточие, т.к. на него падает логическое ударение.

См.: Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.